# How to integrate Mathjax into Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, mathjax

I am trying to integrate the MathJax script into my [Tumblr blog](https://ugupta.tumblr.com/). However, Latex equations are not getting rendered.

I have done the following based on miscellaneous search and MathJax documentation:

```
     <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [[ '$','$']],
          displayMath:  [['$$','$$']],
          processEscapes: true
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
      });
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" async
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?...">
    </script>
```

The code is added in Edit HTML (just before ) of the current theme.

Comment: You might want to share a link to a live page.

Comment: Hi @peter, I have edited the question by adding the link to the blog.

Comment: @peter I solved the problem. The problem was not in the code, but it was with the way I was writing math in the blog. I think when I copy pasted the math formulas they automatically became "code type" and were displayed verbatim. However, when I wrote the math in a new line separately from scratch, MathJax could render it.

Comment: Glad to hear you could work it out.